# Now that Ubuntu is coming to Windows 10, will Windows become a first-class citizen platform for ROS?

Tags: ros, windows, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the Ubuntu user space coming to Windows 10, should we expect ROS to quickly become available on this platform? Or are there kernel dependencies that might cause problems? The number of devices ROS could run on would blow through the roof.

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/30/ubuntu-on-windows-the-ubuntu-userspace-for-windows-developers/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231113/now-that-ubuntu-is-coming-to-windows-10,-will-windows-become-a-first-class-citizen-platform-for-ros?/) by [pondersome](https://answers.ros.org/users/26501/pondersome/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
A comment: Windows is (or will be) a first-class citizen for ROS2. This question is specifically about ROS1 it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If they're really running a recent version of Ubuntu and apt, ROS will probably work.

The core parts of ROS don't require specific support from the kernel, so most of the core functionality like topics and services should work.

Any package that requires a driver (lasers, cameras, etc) will need to be tested on a case-by-case basis. Most of the hardware drivers in ROS are written and maintained by different groups, so each ROS driver is different and has different requirements of the kernel. It's impossible to make a blanket statement about whether all of them will work or not. In the end, the driver support will depend heavily on how well /dev and USB works in Ubuntu on Windows 10.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
Note that interaction with the Win32/64 parts of Windows are not possible at the moment, other than console in/output (I imagine sockets can be used to relay data). Also, re: devices/drivers: afaik those are not accessible from the linux subsystem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-07**:
Agreed. From reading the other posts I do not expect a much hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is a good intro to what it will do here https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/ and http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/04/why-microsoft-needed-to-make-windows-run-linux-software/ specifically addressing some of the limitations of what will be possible in the first release

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1